# How can I remove my selected item duplicate and provide a Please Select option AFTER my selected item in my DropDownlist is bound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu, bind

In my Page Load method I prepopulate the DropDownList with lookups from my database.

```
ddRelationship.DataSource = _dal.GetStandardLookups(Guid.Parse(fhsConstants.fhsRelationship));
        ddRelationship.DataTextField = "LookupDescription";
        ddRelationship.DataValueField = "LookupValue";
        ddRelationship.DataBind();
        ddRelationship.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select", "0"));
```

I then set the existing value from the list in with Populate from database method

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_dal.GetStandardLookupDescription(CurrentDependant.Relationship)) == false)
        {
            ddRelationship.SelectedItem.Value = _dal.GetStandardLookupValue(CurrentDependant.Relationship);
            ddRelationship.SelectedItem.Text = _dal.GetStandardLookupDescription(CurrentDependant.Relationship);
        }
        else
        {
            ddRelationship.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

The issue I am having is that, if populate from database I am no longer able to see my 'Please Select' option and my selected option appears twice! I.e. If the populate from database method is not called I can see 'Please Select', 'Mother', 'Father'... If I populate from database and my value is Father then I can see 'Father', 'Mother', 'Father'...

Is there a way to stop this duplication and retain my Please Select option? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working for me now, albeit that it uses description instead of value:

```
 ddRelationship.ClearSelection();                    
 ddRelationship.Items.FindByText(_dal.GetStandardLookupDescription(CurrentDependant.Relationship)).Selected = true;
```